# Programmatically construct iTunes URL for all territories given iTunes ID?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, itunes

We have an email newsletter for iOS apps, but the iTunes links don't work in all territories even if we remove the country reference.

For instance, this is the USA link for one app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spoof-charades-free-fun-party/id777551771?mt=8

We remove the country code, thinking it would work in other countries (since removing the country code also works inside the US): https://itunes.apple.com/app/id777551771

However, this fails in other countries like China.

Given an app's iTunes ID, how can you programmatically construct an iTunes URL that works in all territories?

Comment: do you know why it fails in China? and what are those other countries?

Comment: not sure why it fails, @JeanLuc

Comment: ok, do you know other countries than China were it fails also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases if you just use `us`, Apple will resolve the country code for you.

Comment: the only downside is the link doesn't redirect to the native app store, e.g., if the user is in china, the app appears in english rather than chinese. it's not perfect, but it's better than displaying nothing. :)

Comment: @Ricky Look like someone downvoted our answers without any explanation. I removed mine.

Answer (score 2):

First I suggest you use [iTunes Link Maker](http://iTunesLinkMaker.com) and **remove the country code** (i.e. "**us**") out of the link and it would always work, open iTunes always and not a browser on the way (if there is iTunes installed on the target system). Using the "US" country code would result in **opening the US App Store** (depends on the target device and OS version), which could make you lose downloads/sales (users would see the english US App Store and would need an account there, it's not the Chinese store!).

You can also **remove the app_name** you don't really need it (if your app name would be changed nothing happen, actually the name is ignored).

Another thing I would check is that on iTunes Connect you **support sales on China** under "Rights and Pricing".

Comment: as mentioned in the question, the link https://itunes.apple.com/app/id777551771 (without country code) fails to work in china even though https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/id777551771 works (with country code).

Comment: @Crashalot Try building it using the iTunesLinkMaker link I've posted, I've done it on my test device and that work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [iTunes Search API for affiliates](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). This is essentially the iTunes Link Maker API. This is an extremely powerful API - you can look up content by ID, bundle id, text strings, etc.

The affiliate linking guidelines can be found [here](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store.html#CountryCodes).

The alternative is to use the older, short linking syntax [described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html).